# Tree structure software

Tags: windows, diagram

I there a program which allows me to create trees, in which branches can be expended and collapsed by clicking a button?

Also is it possible for a branch to eventually loop back to another branch, as well as for one branch to cross, but not connect to another branch? (The data layout is too complex to not cross branches over, and sometimes branches need to loop back to other branches.)

Here is what I mean with looping:

> [image]

Here is what I mean by crossover:

> [image]

Comment: In "crossover", branch C could simply be drawn beneath "data1"

Comment: @mawg yes but not in real life complex scenarios, that was just an example. see here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_utilities_problem

Comment: It's getting on midnight here, so I will try to make more sense in the a.m. Sounds like you know programming, so look into http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php I can't recommend it enough; its plain text input can be generated by any tool that you code Also, you are new here, please tag with operating system & budget (I am guessing Windows & Gratis, but if you state it, we can help - the more help you give us, the more we can give you).